# Why to use @Autowired to run Kafka Streams topology in a Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-annotations

I am trying to run Kafka Streams Topology inside a spring boot application.
In the [example on confluent website](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/spring/hands-on-process-messages-with-kafka-streams/) they did the following:

```
@Component
class Processor {
    @Autowired
    public void process(final StreamsBuilder builder) {
        // the logic to run the topology which is a blocking call
    }
}
```

I think the @Autowired annotation means that the method process will be invoked by the Spring framework.

My question is: Given that the call to the method process is blocking call
is this the best practice to run the topology inside a spring boot application?
Why not run it in a separate thread?

Comment: Why do you think this wouldn't be ran in a separate thread? I.e. Spring's Component Scanner thread

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` instructs Spring to inject an existing StreamsBuilder bean as a parameter to the `process(...)` function. This is done while bootstrapping the application context, so it will not block the running topology itself which is started as a seperate thread via some kind of `new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);`

Therefore this is absolutely okay to do.